# Synchronize oracle ddl changes

Tags: oracle

I am using oracle with sqldeveloper and have two remote schemas: Schema A and Schema B. I need to update schema B according to schema A. Currently I am using database copy feature of sqldeveloper to manually copy any ddl changes such as a new table, a new constraint added to schema A. Is there a way I can automate the process like have schema B updated automatically every time a ddl change occurs in A? I went through some replication tools but they had quite complex procedures and were not free.

Comment: Have you considered [DDL triggers](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/oracle-plsql-programming/9780596805401/ch19s02.html)?

Comment: The correct solution to this problem is to **write your DDL changes as scripts**. Store them in a source control repository and run those scripts against all the relevant schemas in all the relevant environments. This sort of thing is standard good practice in other types of code, I don't know why people persist with bad practice when it comes to database programs.

Comment: @abra I think oracle streams is deprecated in 18c, so should not be used.